# Like button plugin goes wrong on IE (inside hidden div)

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I am having a problem with the visibility of my LIKE BUTTON social plugin. 
the problem only occurs on IE (it works just fine in Chrome & Firefox), and only to the type of "box_count".

I tried multiple ways to implement the plugin (iframe, fb:like etc...) and the result in IE is the same (as the picture demonstrates in the following link):

[print screen of the messed-up FB LIKE-BUTTON](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/1892/fberror.png)

The problem is ONLY while i'm toggling a div (in a "talkbacks" area), while to plugin is inside a DIV with "Display:NONE" (before the display changes to "display:block" by clicking on another link).
I think the property "display:none" effects the plugin on IE somehow, altough the display changes after toggling the div.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post some code so that people will be better able to help you.

Comment: <fb:like href="SOME-LINK" send="false" layout="box_count" width="70" show_faces="true" font="arial"></fb:like>    -    Thats the code (followd by the regular plugin script). this code is inside <Div id="1" style="DISPLAY:none;">. thx!

Comment: Play with the CSS in chrome developer tool or firebug to find out what style you'll need to change then add that style to your css file. Another option is using addthis.com which is easy to use and customize.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a div with an ID that starts with a number - it's invalid.

Try and use the HTML version:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="70" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div>
```

Make sure you don't have any CSS styles that alter the width of the DIV - as Anagio said - use  the developer tools on chrome/firefox to inspect the div element that has shrunk. Also look for any javascript errors.

If you can post the actual URL, people will be able to offer more help